# Error in STM Code after compliling on Ubuntu

Tags: c, scp

I'm following [this](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/Getting_started/STM32MP1_boards/STM32MP157x-DK2/Develop_on_Arm%C2%AE_Cortex%C2%AE-A7/Create_a_simple_hello-world_application) tutorial for setting up the STm32MP157C-DK2 microcontroller. On the steps for creating a basic hello world program, I am able to compile a program and upload it to the STM through scp. However, when I try to execute the program, I get the following error:
`./gtk_hello_world: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string`

Any ideas for why this is? I have a file called `Makefile` in which I pasted the code from step 3. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the output of `$CC --version`: `arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0 Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Output of `file ./gtk_hello_world`: `./gtk_hello_world: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=8ead7efdeb72bdb56917d3e716549f636095e92c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped`

Comment: is your gtk_hello_world.c *exactly* like the one in the tutorial?

Comment: That sounds like a *shell* error - as though you're trying to execute the compiled binary file with a shell interpreter, like `sh ./gtk_hello_world`

Comment: My gtk_hello_world.c is _exactly_ like the tutorial one.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I am executing it by running ```./gtk_hello_world```.

Comment: Can we just check that you are in the SDK's cross-compile environment here? what is the output of `$CC --version` from where you ran the `make` command? what is the output of `file ./gtk_hello_world` before you scp it to the board?

Comment: Output of ```$CC --version```: 
```arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.```

Output of ```file ./gtk_hello_world```:
```./gtk_hello_world: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=8ead7efdeb72bdb56917d3e716549f636095e92c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped```

Comment: OK so although your environment's CC says `arm-ostl-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, your Makefile has somehow managed to create an ELF x86-64 binary. BTW please [edit] the above information into your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136752/discussion-between-ben-underwood-and-steeldriver).